# Revit External application running outside of API context is not allowed

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm trying to start a transaction inside my code but, as you can see in the title, it generate an error. I have reading many thread on External Application but don't correctly know how it work.

This is the code I use to start my transaction :
inside my form :

```
private void Loading_FA_only()//Lance l'import en boucle suivant les items dans la file d'attente
    {
        foreach(FileInfo fi in selected_rfas_donnees)
        {
            Loading_Family.famille = fi;
            Loading_Family lf = new Loading_Family();
            lf.Execute(Command.uiapplication);
            Listing_succes(Loading_Family.succes, fi);
        }
        selected_rfas.Clear();
        selected_rfas_donnees.Clear();
        Update_Compteur();
    }
```

and that what I try to execute :

```
public class Loading_Family : IExternalEventHandler
{
    public static FileInfo famille;
    public static bool succes;
    public void Execute(UIApplication uiapp)
    {
        UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
        Application app = uiapp.Application;
        Document doc = uidoc.Document;

        // Access current selection

        Selection sel = uidoc.Selection;

        // Retrieve elements from database

        FilteredElementCollector col
          = new FilteredElementCollector(doc)
            .WhereElementIsNotElementType()
            .OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.INVALID)
            .OfClass(typeof(Wall));

        // Filtered element collector is iterable

        foreach (Element e in col)
        {
            Debug.Print(e.Name);
        }

        // Modify document within a transaction

        succes = false;
        string nom_famille = famille.Name.Remove(famille.Name.Length - 4, 4);
        FilteredElementCollector familles_doc = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(Family));
        foreach (Element elmt in familles_doc)
        {
            if (elmt.Name == nom_famille)
            {
                var result = TaskDialog.Show("CPF - Importation", "Il semblerait que " + nom_famille + " soit déjà présent dans votre projet.\nVoullez-vous le remplacer ?", TaskDialogCommonButtons.Yes | TaskDialogCommonButtons.No);
                if (result == TaskDialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    using (Transaction tr = new Transaction(doc, "Importer la famille"))
                    {
                        tr.Start();
                        doc.LoadFamily(famille.FullName);
                        tr.Commit();
                        tr.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (Transaction tr = new Transaction(doc, "Importer la famille"))
                {
                    tr.Start();
                    doc.LoadFamily(famille.FullName);
                    tr.Commit();
                    tr.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        familles_doc = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
        foreach (Element elmt in familles_doc)
        {
            if (elmt.Name == nom_famille) { succes = true; }
            else { succes = false; }
        }

        using (Transaction tx = new Transaction(doc))
        {
            tx.Start("Transaction Name");
            tx.Commit();
        }

    }
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "my event";
    }
}
```

I'm desperate with this. I absolutely don't know how theirs "ExternalEventHandler" or "ExternalApplication" work.
Thank for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple. Use external events and make sure the external event is declared inside the constructor of MyForm.  Personally I've never used ShowDialog because it blocks the user access to the rest of the UI.

Comment: I understand that is what I have to do but don't know how :) I tried to search code example on internet but not very satisfy of what I found. I also watch your [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHMwd4U_Lrs) a couple of time to see how you are working but, eh, there is my post :)

Comment: Fork my 19 techniques project from github. That uses a modeless form with 18 discrete external event codes. https://github.com/joshnewzealand/Revit-API-Playpen-CSharp . It is only hard the first time.

Comment: I watched your link and I try [this](https://imgur.com/gallery/0wsjTeH). I let you see the problem. I think i don't clearly understand what I read :)

Comment: The ExternalEvent.Create(lf) has to go inside the Interface_CPF() constructor method (not loading event).

Comment: Of course. My Loading_selected method is inside the Interface_CPF() class. You can see [here](https://imgur.com/gallery/ro1kOq4) the full Interface_CPF class

Comment: but is the Loading_selected method called from inside the 'constructor', the constructor is the method that contains InitializeComponent();  your 99% there

Comment: No it's not. I create Loading_selected method by myself. Why have I to put it in the constructor ? How to call it if it is in the constructor ?

Comment: once it is created in the constructor, you can call it with .Raise() whereever you want.

Comment: But when the constructor will start, it will start the code too.. no ?
When my code use ExternalEvent creation  = ExternalEvent.Create(lf); it start the code inside the function or not ? [Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/m88ptI8) a picture to see where i have to put this piece of code.

Comment: Ooook ! I got it ! Thank you soo much for your time ! I will answer my problem by a new post for more clarity to other people. You are the best !

Comment: Could you accept this as the solution...it would be my first.

Comment: Can we detect if an ExternalEvent is ended ? My code is running during the event, it is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Please work through the [Revit API getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2). That explains all the required fundamentals of the Revit API and its architecture, including how external applications and commands are implemented and used.

Please note that [the Revit API cannot be used at all outside of a valid Revit API context](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/12/external-event-and-10-year-forum-anniversary.html#2), and such a context is provided exclusively by the callbacks issues by Revit.exe while running and loading a Revit add-in.

Therefore, the statement you make in your description is expected and desired: a Revit external application can never run outside of a valid Revit API context and is therefore indeed not allowed.

Please spell check your texts before submitting them, especially the title, since  typos such as the one in your description make it harder to find an issue.

Comment: I already consult your website.
The simple problem i have here is to give the correct UIApplication parameter of my Execute method but don't how.

Comment: When I use MyForm.Show() in Command class in Execute method I'm outside Revit API when i try to execute a new transaction in my command class but in an other method.
When I use MyForm.ShowDialog() at the same place, it's ok but when I try to place a family in a view, it doesn't work because i cannot close MyForm.

Check this problem [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-et-bim-francais/placement-d-un-element-de-detail-avec-visual-studio/td-p/9464148)